# Is there a way to mock ValidationErrors in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I have a function that parses different fields in the array of type `ValidationError` to generate custom error messages something like the following function.

```
func foo(err validator.ValidationErrors) []string {
    var errStr []string
    for _, e := range err {
       tag := e.Tag()
       field := e.Field()
       errStr = append(errStr, tag + ":" + field)
    }
    return errStr
}
```

I want to  write unit test for this function to ensure that the custom message is as expected. How can I mock a variable of type `validator.ValidationError`. Below is the structure of ValidationError:

`type ValidationErrors []FieldError`

`FieldError` is an interface which contains functions (such as `Tag()`, `Field()`, etc.) to get error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unit-test a function that takes `validator.ValidationErrors`, just construct the test value yourself, using a type (possibly a struct) that implements `FieldError`.

The methods are not many, but if you want to implement only those that your function calls, you can embed `validator.FieldError` in the struct type:

```
type mockFieldError struct {
    validator.FieldError
    tag   string
    field string
}

func (e mockFieldError) Tag() string { return e.tag }

func (e mockFieldError) Field() string { return e.field }
```

And construct `validator.ValidationErrors` (note that the embedded `validator.FieldError` is uninitialized, so make sure the function under test doesn't call other methods you didn't implement, or it will panic):

```
    ve := validator.ValidationErrors{
        mockFieldError{tag: "a", field: "field1"},
        mockFieldError{tag: "b", field: "field2"},
    }
```

So now calling `foo` with the above value compiles and returns a string that you can assert against your expected output:

```
    s := foo(ve)
    fmt.Println(s) // [a:field1 b:field2]
```

Full playground: https://go.dev/play/p/-btZ6lrKk4V